# PowerPoint VBA - Insert Symbol using macro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to insert symbol in PowerPoint from FontAwesome icon library.
Unicode value example - f001
Here is my code-

```
Sub InsertSymbol()

        Dim txtBox As Shape
        Dim s As String

        s = "f" & "001"

        'Add text box
        Set txtBox = Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1) _
            .Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=100)

        'Add symbol to text box
        txtBox.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertSymbol _
            FontName:="FontAwesome", CharNumber:=s, Unicode:=msoTrue

    End Sub
```

Error - runtime error 13 
Type Misatch.
Anyone please could fix this?

Comment: `CharNumber` requires a `long` - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/textrange-insertsymbol-method-powerpoint). If you try to insert this symbol manually, can you see its Unicode (hex) value?

Comment: @BigBen 1. Dim  s as long shows Run-time error '13':
type mismatch
2. I can only see character code start from F00...

Comment: I agree - it would if you then try to assign a `string` to it with `s = "f" & "001"`. My thought was to get this character's Unicode (hex) value and then convert that to a `long`.

Comment: @BigBen is there any way to find out character's Unicode (hex) value? I've tried on FontAwesome website, forum but didn't get a single clue.

Comment: When manually inserting a symbol from the Insert toolbar... there is a Character Code field, above the Insert button... You might even be able to use the ASCII value, instead of Unicode (hex). I don't have FontAwesome installed but have successfully inserted other symbols this way...

Comment: Is this where you see "character code start from F00..."?

Comment: The code works on ASCII (decimal) and ASCII (hex) but not on Unicode(hex) value. Just tried on FA icon library first value "F001" [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons/music?style=solid&from=io)

Comment: @BigBen "Is this where you see "character code start from F00..."?" - YES

Comment: Try using `61441` instead of `"f" & "001"`. If that doesn't work I will install Font Awesome and try to replicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CharNumber` requires a `long` - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/textrange-insertsymbol-method-powerpoint).

After a bit of research - your Unicode value `"F001"` needs to be converted from hex to decimal. Any online hex to decimal converter will give you the corresponding value `61441`: [hex to decimal converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html?x=F001).